# Как убрать эту фиолетовую анимацию в scrollView?

Tags: android

При скроллинге до самого низа появляется вот такая вот фиолетовая анимация, как её убрать скажите пожалуйста.
[image: Фиолетовая штука появляется]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это `overscroll`, когда вы доходите до начала/конца списка сверху/снизу появляется такая дуга (**overscroll edge effect**).
Что бы *выключить* добавьте эту строку в xml для `scrollView`

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

[Как изменить цвет overscroll (eng)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27342957/7540461)